# Error: "No shape named tikz@f@1-1-2 is known"

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-cd

I typed:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    E \arrow[r] E 
\end{tikzcd}
```

and I get the error "No shape named tikz@f@1-1-2 is known." I have tried many things and don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `tikz-cd` requires nodes to be separated by the `&` symbol. Here's a minimal document. For future questions, it's really helpful (and usually essential) to add such a document to your question (even if it yields an error.)  See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} E \arrow[r] & E \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]